# SqlAlchemy commit after using update() function without using a session

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy, commit

My selections work but my updates and deletes do not.

```
db_jb = create_engine(jb)
self.jobs = Table('Job', MetaData(jb), autoload=True)
# select - works
ss = select(self.jobs).where(
    self.jobs.c.job_guid == jobGuid
).limit(1)
rs = ss.execute()
rows = [r for r in rs]
rs.close()
# update - does not work
su = update(self.jobs, mysql_limit=1).where(
    self.jobs.c.job_guid == jobGuid
).values(jobStatus=status)
# does not have an affect
su.execution_options(autocommit=True)
rs = su.execute()
rs.close()
```

Prettify the `su` variable and the query is correct but its not being committed

```
str(su.compile(dialect=None, compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
```

How do I commit my changes without using a Session?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to execute `COMMIT` as a raw statement, like

```
db_jb.execute('COMMIT')
```

You could also put `db_jb.execute('BEGIN')` just before `ss = ...` to explicitly start a transaction

Comment: I found out that I was skipping my `rs = su.execute()` command because I had a command line switch for debugging... Doh! Even though the code works, thank you for answering my question